# Google map not showing in android activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

In my android app I want to have a MainActivity with a google map occupying the entire screen.

My problem is that the google map does not display a map, only the google logo in the bottom left corner:

[image]

Here are the relevant parts of the main activity where the map should be displayed:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        setupLayout();

        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
```

Here is the xml for the content of the main activity which holds the google map fragment:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          tools:context="com.purringcat.stray.view.activity.MainActivity"/>
```

Here is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.purringcat.stray">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:name=".Stray"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".view.activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".view.activity.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".view.activity.SignUpActivity">
        </activity>
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: this usually is caused by incorrect maps integration (wrong tokens/keys/certificates)

Comment: Could it be related to the fact that I am not using a FragmentActivity?

Comment: 1) Make sure you have added API key in your project.
2) Make sure your api is enabled on the Google console.
3) Make sure SHA-1 which you have provided is correct.

Comment: `FragmentActivity` I don't think that it is related. I'm sure that you are using wrong API key, or generated wrong fingerprint for the maps.

Comment: There seems to be no issues with the api_key or anything to do with maps integration. I am really confused as to what is happening as I seem to have no errors or bugs.

Comment: have you added the google maps key in the release folder

Answer (score 9):

You need to enable google map api from google console for your project. And also you need to download json file from the console.

**1. Go to [google console](https://console.developers.google.com/)**

**2. click on your project.**

**3. Click on library section from left menu panel. see below image**

[image]

4. In google maps api, click on **Google maps android api**
5. Than enable that.
6. Now Goto [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/)
7. Click on your project and goto project settings and download the json file.
8. Add that json file in your application.

Comment: I know that, I literally just enabled it on the google console, then added the api key to the manifest.

Comment: How do I enable the map?

Comment: and you have downloaded the json file also?

Comment: I have the google-services.json file in the app folder of the project.

Comment: Then it should work your code is perfect. Once try to change appcompactActivity to FragementActivity. I don't think it affects but just try once

Comment: I change the activity to a fragment activity but now I get an error on this code: `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

Comment: Just comment it and run it for once to see it worked or not.

Answer (score 2):

I just checked with google map like yours.

Just compare your code with mine.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

}

And Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Note: You have to create a project in google

[click here to visit the google console](http://console.developers.google.com)

Replace your Key value in the google_maps_api

```
<resources>


<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">Your Key</string>
```

Hope this works for you.

PS:  you can generate google map activity from android studio.

Answer (score 1):

Add this permissions to menifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

OR Check in google console is API  ENABLED

OR Check your google_api_key

Comment: I have included the question to include the manifest. I have enabled the API and added the api key which starts with AIz

Answer (score 1):

Include the following code in `AndroidManifest.xml` file, within the `application` part:

```
<uses-library
    android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
    android:required="false" />
```

See documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#specify_requirement_for_apache_http_legacy_library).

Answer (score 1):

Google maps likes to get the different activity lifecycle states. So you should send it: `map_view.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` and `map_view.onResume()`. It also likes `onPause()`, `onLowMemory()`, `onSaveInstanceState(outState)`, `onDestroy()` if they occur.

Answer (score 1):

click on Restrict key and then in API restrictions->don't Restrict key while creating api

Answer (score 0):

1) Please update google play services

2) Please append your api key in the url

Ex:-"**https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/**" + output + "?" + parameters + "&key=" + MY_API_KEY;

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have given these permisssions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and check if the WiFi of AVD is on and your PC is connected to internet.

I was getting the same problems, and following the above mentioned steps I was able to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the Activity is Opening and the map is not visible even if you are giving Google_map_key , then one solution that worked for me is that i created a new Google map API KEY by copying the link in the google_maps_api.xml and pasting in the browser. Select a project or create a project it will land you on the page where google API KEY is ready copy it and paste it in the place given in the instruction .it will work.

Answer (score 0):

All Coding things done. check properly.
then must to do TWO Things with APp.

1. add SHA -1 Key in Firebase console.
2. Dowanload and add this json file in your code.
   THis PC -> "Your project folder" -> app -> "here Put and Update json file"
3. Go to Google cloud Console.
   API & Services -> Credentials -> Android key (auto created by Firebase)  -> copy "API Key".
   [image]
4. put this API Key in Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

1. The Google Console have Keys like our projects and also auto created.
2. But for the **map** Related task use only following key.
3. But, Further keep in mind, Enable all the **Google map API**.
4. The Google Console Have the Key which Name is

   ```
       **"Browser key (auto created by Firebase)"**
   ```

[image]

5. Put this key in your project file in **build.app** as an ***"SERVER_KEY"***

Ex..
[image]

6. Check the ***"Package Name and SHA-1 Key"*** added in a Key which we used for MAP function.
   [image]

and your Map is Enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar issue after updating my app to Android-13 and just found the solution.

After following the standard steps of [setting-up google cloud project](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/cloud-setup), I created API key and made it secure by [restricting it](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key#restrict_key) to my project package with my signing-key fingerprint.

Here was the major problem. Initially, I just added the SHA-1 fingerprint of the signing key which I am using to create the app-bundle. But missed to add the Google generated signing key, which I found in the google-play console (Google play console > Setup (in left drawer menu) > App signing).

As soon as you will add the **SHA-1 certificate fingerprint** of **App signing key certificate** in the Android restrictions list of your [MAP_API_KEY](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials), the map starts loading.

I hope, this helps. Thanks!