# App crashes when running maps activity

Tags: android, performance, kotlin

My projects Map activity is not working
I just pasted the api key in place `google_maps_api.xml`
and clicked run

Logcat:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5
>                     Process: com.example.appmy.lofind, PID: 10901
>                     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion;
>                         at el.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):3)
>                         at ek.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):4)
>                         at em.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):51)
>                         at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.ap.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):11)
>                         at dw.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):16)
>                         at dw.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):61)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/app_chimera/m/MapsDynamite.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000006/MapsDynamite.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
>                         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:126)
>                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
>                         at ad.loadClass(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):25)
>                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>                         at el.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):3) 
>                         at ek.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):4) 
>                         at em.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):51) 
>                         at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.ap.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):11) 
>                         at dw.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):16) 
>                         at dw.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12848026@12.8.48 (040700-196123505):61) 
>   E/SchedPolicy: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<s>The same problem here when using target SDK 28. Reverting to SDK 27 solved the problem.</s>

---

Don't revert your target SDK.

Better use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/50944537/5710605

Comment: @MajdNaji check Eduard's other answer. I think that's a better solution than downgrading.

Comment: Reverting to SDK 27 is not a solution, don't add broken windows to your house. "Pragmatic programmer"

Answer (score 63):

I've found another solution at
[Android Google maps java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50782806/android-google-maps-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-lorg-a/50794266#50794266)

Just add this in your manifest:

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

---

**Update:**

Starting from Google Maps SDK version **16.1.0** you can skip adding the solution above as the tag has been added to the AndroidManifest of the maps library.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/releases#2019-02-06

> Added the following declaration to the AndroidManifest.xml to support
>   the Apache HTTP client on Android P and above. After updating to
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0 you can remove this
>   line from your own AndroidManifest.xml. (Issue [117591497](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117591497))
>
> `<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>`

Comment: Thanks. I prefer this to the accepted answer. I read somewhere else on SO to include `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` instead. It didn't work in my case, but thoughts on it?

Answer (score 3):

Put this in the Manifest  tag:

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

More info: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79478779

as google documentation said:

> If you are using com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0 or
>   below and your app is targeting API level 28 (Android 9.0) or above,
>   you must include the following declaration within the 
>   element of AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Why add an answer, that has already been given by Eduard Bosch?