# SchedPolicy: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted

Tags: android, google-maps

I am facing this issue in my Logcat while I run my android app. Does anyone know about this issue and how to fix it?

The dependencies are:

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'  
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar:library:1.0.2'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: Did you find anything on this issue?

Comment: No. @RanaRanvijaySingh

Comment: have u tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50944537/2556660

Comment: Possible Duplication im facing the same problem, i found the answer here its well explained in this answer [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50897054/app-crashes-when-running-maps-activity/50944537#50944537)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50897054/app-crashes-when-running-maps-activity/50944537#50944537

Comment: This answer did not work in my case.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure about exact solution but I have fixed same issue by avoiding use of Dialog with Maps. Especially when we show dialog while map is animating or marker/polyline is drawing.

Comment: Any news about this? I have found the same problem.

Comment: I have removed the dialog, and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well! I found out that it was because my API was not enabled

Try to enable all required APIs from google cloud (like geolocation, places API, geocoding...).

try it and give me feedback