# set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted. Android MapFragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, android-fragments

Hi i am java laungage for a  having a Map fragment,on that if i frequently open dialog and perform some operation.
i am getting

> set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted

i have already tried this solution [App crashes when running maps activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50897054/app-crashes-when-running-maps-activity/50944537#50944537)
But the issue is same.
When did some R & D. It showed showing Dialog on Map fragment causes this Issue.
Is there any way to resolve it...?
Adding tag to manifest is not resolving my Issue.

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

Comment: Can you please post your logcat, maps activity, app-level build.gradle and manifest files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SchedPolicy: set\_timerslack\_ns write failed: Operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51908975/schedpolicy-set-timerslack-ns-write-failed-operation-not-permitted)

Answer (score 1):

Another reason: On Android 11 if you try to access a permission together with a permission that needs to be requested **before** the others:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(sourceActivity,
                                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
                                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},...
```

Location permissions have to be requested before the background one: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-the-android-11-developer-preview-permission-changes-61b18fb658

Answer (score 0):

This issue was mainly happening due to open of dialog,other view components when Map is Showing.

My issue was different which was occuring due to DB error .finally resolved it..

I got mistaken here,Bcoz it was Frequently  showing this error in log.

Comment: It is happening to me because of a bottom sheet dialog that opens on top of the map. is it important to fix it ?