# Android Studio: Google maps apk blank

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, apk

I'm trying to make an app, following the steps of a tutorial, but it seems that there is an error, my google maps is showing blank, as i will show in the next image:

[image: Google image]

Now, I'm not sure what the error could be, since I'm following the steps of the tutorial, but it would seem that it is outdated. I have created my key in the google web and it should be running.

First part of the code, where I check if im connected to internet (it works fine):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btnNet);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkConnection();
            }
        });
    }
    protected boolean isConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
           return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public void checkConnection(){
        if (isConnected()){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Estamos conectados!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No stamos conectados!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Second part, the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.netinfo">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the "MyLocation" functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NetInfo">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I did create the MapActivity from android studio, so I didn't change a thing there, but just in case here is the code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Also, this is what i get from the logcat.

[image: Error]

EDIT 1: Added the permission ACCESS_INTERNET and the error in logcat disapeard, but I keep not getting the map

EDIT 2: MAPS SDK FOR ANDROID is enabled:

[image]

Comment: Make sure you've added the correct API key. And remove any restrictions which you've added to the API key from Google Cloud Console until you have tested everything. Also remember, it may take a while for your changes to get applied which you've made to the API key.

Comment: I'm really confused, but it might be a problem with my key, saddly I think I should search for help in real time lol

Comment: Do the error logs say anything about the API key?

Comment: Not really, I only get this errors in logcat

2021-04-01 09:46:08.429 2057-2183/? W/AppOps: Noting op not finished: uid 10098 pkg com.google.android.gms code 41 time=1617288363431 duration=0
2021-04-01 09:46:10.409 11619-11690/com.example.netinfo W/example.netinf: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
2021-04-01 09:46:10.423 11619-11690/com.example.netinfo W/example.netinf: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)

Comment: Have you had a look at this thread: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365369/google-map-not-showing-in-android-activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365369/google-map-not-showing-in-android-activity) ? An old thread but a lot of the suggestions are still valid.

Comment: Hi srinij, I haved added a new edit, I hope that's correct, also I didn't understood this step in the link you gave me.  "3) Make sure SHA-1 which you have provided is correct." thank you for everything and i'll wait for your reply to search if there is something else missing to make it work :(

Comment: I have used now a code that's suppused to work, with my key, but it didn't work. I'm assuming now that the problem is with my key 100% sure

Comment: @HenryAranda you can refer to [this developer link](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started#api-key) for the API set up. There are three steps listed here that need to be completed. I did notice that you have the `@string/google_maps_key` defined. Is that key the right one?